# Мапинг параметров запроса по позиции

Tags: c#, ado.net, dapper

В общем, формирую DataTable, далее в нее заношу данные.

Затем, хочу эти данные слить в Access бд.
Я генерю запрос на INSERT ручками, например

```
INSERT INTO TableName (f1,f2,f3) values (@f1,@f2,@f3)
```

Далее, хочу в цикле пробежаться по каждой DataRow и выполнить запрос.

Выполняю execute через Dapper, вида:

```
_conn.Execute(cmd, row.ItemArray)
```

И ловлю ошибку, что недостаточно параметров... Похоже, он пытается связать все по имени.

Возможно ли сделать связку по позиции? Или может быть есть другой способ, где можно не заморачиваться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dapper мапит параметры только по имени (как и ADO.NET, впрочем). Возможно, самый простой способ -- использовать анонимный тип:

```
connection.Query<Dog>("select Age = @Age, Id = @Id", new { Age = (int?)null, Id = guid });
```

Comment: А можно сделать анонимный тип по ходу выполнения кода, если заранее неизвестно то, что будет вставляться?

Comment: @iluxa1810 нет, анонимный тип требует знания названий свойств. Если они заранее неизвестны, используйте `DynamicParameters`.

Comment: Даже через dynamic нельзя?

Comment: @iluxa1810 `dynamic` тут вообще сбоку стоит. Возможно, `ExpandoObject` сработает, попробуйте. Хотя по сути это то же самое, что и дапперовский `DynamicParameters`.